# minimum coin with no DP

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

```
public int MinCoins(int[] change, int cents)
{
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    int coins = 0;
    int cent = 0;
    int finalCount = cents;
    for (int i = change.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        cent = cents;

        for (int j = i; j <= change.Length - 1; j++)
        {
            coins += cent / change[j];
            cent = cent % change[j];
            if (cent == 0) break;
        }

        if (coins < finalCount)
        {
            finalCount = coins;
        }
        coins = 0;
    }
    sw.Stop();
    var elapsedMs = sw.Elapsed.ToString(); ;
    Console.WriteLine("time for non dp " + elapsedMs);
    return finalCount;
}

public  int MinCoinsDp(int[] change, int cents)
{
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    int[] minCoins = new int[cents + 1];

    for (int i = 1; i <= cents; i++)
    {
        minCoins[i] = 99999;

        for (int j = 0; j < change.Length; j++)
        {

            if(i >= change[j])
            {

                int n = minCoins[i - change[j]] + 1;

                if (n < minCoins[i])
                    minCoins[i] = n;
            }
        }
    }
    sw.Stop();
    var elapsedMs = sw.Elapsed.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine("time for dp " + elapsedMs);

    return minCoins[cents];
}
```

I have written a minimum number of coins programs using iterative and Dynamic Programming. I have seen a lot of blogs discussing about DP for this problem. Iterative solutions has running time O(numberOfCoins * numberofCoins) and DP has O(numberofcoins*arraySize) roughly same. Which one is better? Please suggest good book for advanced algorithms.

Please run with {v1 > v2 > v3 > v4} like {25,10,5}

Comment: Your code prints 1 instead of 2 if you run `Console.WriteLine(MinCoins(new int[]{3,2}, 4));`

Answer (score 1):

I see that you're trying to measure running times of both algorithms and decide which one is better.

Well, there is a more important thing about your algorithms. The first one is unfortunately incorrect. For example, please consider the following input:

Suppose we want to exchange `100` and available coins have the following nominals: `5, 6, 90, 96`. The best that we can do is to use `3` coins: `5, 5, 90`. However, your solution returns `1`